# Is there a way to force leader lines to polyline centroids in ArcGIS Desktop 10?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, labeling, annotation

I'm making a pretty standardized set of maps that include alphabetical labels for specific stream segments.  As it stands, all my label leader lines snap to the downstream end of my polylines.  My current workaround is to convert labels to annotation and hand-place them but this is getting to be a real time sink.  Thus I ask: is there a setting I'm missing, or other way to get leader lines to snap to a line centroid?

Full disclosure: [edited to add] Running ArcEditor license level.  I don't have the Maplex extension and am not likely to get it.

Comment: This is an aside but as of 10.1 Maplex is [included in ArcGIS for Desktop](http://www.esri.com/software/arcgis/extensions/maplex) core product at all license levels.  That may be of no assistance but, *if* you have an ArcInfo license [Feature To Point](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00170000003m000000) may be.  You could then label the points (which you hide).

Comment: PolyGeo, on the strength of your comment I got all our machines bumped up to 10.1 - Maplex is exactly what I needed.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I originally suggested this as an aside but since you said it provided a solution I will now post it as an Answer.

As of 10.1 Maplex is [included in ArcGIS for Desktop](http://www.esri.com/software/arcgis/extensions/maplex) core product at all license levels.

If you have an ArcInfo license, you could create points at your line centroids using [Feature To Point](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00170000003m000000) and then label the points (which you hide).